# Getting list of attributes for all methods in class

Tags: c#

I'm attempting to use a custom attribute to generate a list of commands (string) that a user would issue into my console application and the corresponding method will be executed. I'm currently stuck, my command list is always empty.

Here's my attribute:

```
public class ImporterAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string Command { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the class:

```
public class DataProcessor
{
    public List<ImporterAttribute> Commands { get; set; }

    public DataProcessor()
    {
        //Use reflection to collect commands from attributes
        Commands = GetCommands(typeof(DataProcessor));
    }

    public static List<ImporterAttribute> GetCommands(Type t)
    {
        var commands = new List<ImporterAttribute>();

        MemberInfo[] MyMemberInfo = t.GetMethods();

        foreach (MemberInfo member in MyMemberInfo)
        {
            var att = (ImporterAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(member, typeof(ImporterAttribute));

            if (att == null) continue;

            var command = new ImporterAttribute();
            command.Command = att.Command;
            commands.Add(command);
        }

        return commands;
    }

    [Importer(Command = "?")]
    private string Help()
    {
        return "Available commands: " + (from c in Commands select c.Command).Aggregate((a, x) => a + " " + x);
    }

    [Importer(Command = "Q")]
    private void Quit()
    {
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
}
```

Then I use a switch statement to check user input against the command list and run the requested method. So my question is: why is my command list always null? I imagine I just misunderstood something in [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/71s1zwct(v=vs.110).aspx).

Bonus question: does anyone have a better/more practical approach that they use/have used to tackle this feature?

Comment: Could you rewrite your example into a [mcve] (just a console app) so that we can copy/paste/compile/run/reproduce without having to rework it ourselves?

Comment: (But to start with `GetMethods` without a binding flag only returns public methods, and you don't have any public methods with attributes...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is that your methods are private. `GetMethods` by default only retrieve public methods, so if you change your `Help` and `Quit` method signature to `public`, you'll get 2 commands.

If you want to keep them private,you can use [BindingFlags](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags(v=vs.110).aspx) like this:

```
t.GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

Comment: Yep, that fixed it right up. While I don't mind having them public in this specific scenario, is there a way that this works with `privates`?